# Initialize component again on hot replacement when using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I was working on a react.js app with create-react-app, and the hot replacement/reloading feature is useful in most cases, but since one of my component needs to be initialized, it's always fail if a hot replacement happens when the file changes.

For example:

```
// my-component.ts
class MyComponent {
  private hasInit = false;

  init() {
    this.hasInit = true;
  }

  doSomething() {
    if (!this.hasInit) {
      throw new Error('Not initialized');
    }
  }
}

export const myComponent = new MyComponent();
```

In another file to use it:

```
// usage.ts
import { myComponent } from './my-component';

function RootView() {
  useEffect(() => {
    myComponent.init();
  }, []);

  <MyButton onClick={() => { myComponent.doSomething() }} />
}
```

So when the `my-component.ts` has been changed, the `myComponent` in `usage.ts` will be hot replaced, but it won't been re-initialized, so the `doSomething` call failed.

Is there someway, technically, or with some pattern that can solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You need to force render, anyway this pattern you using is not widely used (never seen it)

Comment: @DennisVash I'm new to reactjs, so what's the regular pattern? I just want to keep things simple so I'm using this way. It works without issue except hot reloading.

Comment: You are showing your solution and not the actual problem you trying to solve, if you add a reproducible example in a sandbox I can try and show a solution related to the specific problem. See https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Either way, for your code to work, you need to use force render (check docs), since just changing objects/classes doesn't trigger render in React

Comment: @DennisVash I don't want the UI to re-render, since the issue won't happen in prod. It's an issue I want to avoid when using create-react-app in development.

Comment: @DennisVash The requirement is: having a singleton service (`myComponent` here) which requires initialization at the beginning - then if the file changes and after create-react-app's hot reload, it will be initialized again.

Comment: You can try ejecting your webpack configuration and adding middleware for hot reloading. See examples: gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted

Comment: @DennisVash That's too much still. The solution should not be more complicated than the problem. :)

Comment: @DennisVash BTW your code doesn't fix the issue though. It seems the hot reload doesn't re-render the component. It's just replacing the instance in the code without re-render the component.